# How can I print a board using a two dimensional array?

Tags: c++

I want to print a 5x5 board for a game, at the moment I can only print 5 lines while populating the array. My board currently looks like this:

[image: current image]

Which is technically a 2 row 5 columns board.

This is the output I expect:

[image: expected]

The problem is that I need a 5x5 version of that same board but it only prints 5 lines (which is the size of the array).

I've tried changing the for loop many times but nothing has worked so far
This is my code:

```
    //
    // Created by renan on 31/08/2019.
    //

    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Board.h"

    void Board::displayBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {          //ROWS and COLS 
    are integers with value 5
                for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                    board[row][col] = ' ';

                    if (row % 2 == 0) {
                        cout << " ---";
                    } else {
                        if (col == 0) {
                            cout << "|";
                        }
                        if(board[row][col] == ' '){
                            cout << setw(4) << "|";
                        } else {
                            cout << setw(1) << board[row][col] << " |";
                        }
                    }
                }
                cout << endl;


        }


    }
```

### Board.h

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Board {
    private:
        static const int ROWS = 11;
        static const int COLS = 5;
        char board[ROWS][COLS];
    public:
        void displayBoard();


    };
```

Comment: There is missing code. While it's probably easy enough to give you this output, it's more helpful if you provide a [mcve]. That is, give just enough runnable code to reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also, show us the output you want an the output you get. You say that it prints five lines as if that's bad; how many lines do you want it to print?

Comment: You probably need to change `ROWS` to the number of rows you need (assuming your board is big enough). That's just a guess, though.

Comment: I added the expected output, if i change the number of ROWS then the array this function creates will be bigger than 5x5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected and simplified your code a bit. Hope it will help you to understand what was wrong with your code.

```
void drawHorizontalSeparater() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << " ---";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void drawSeparatedValues(int row) {
    cout << "|";

    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        board[row][col] = ' ';

        cout << " " << board[row][col] << " |";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void displayBoard() {
    drawHorizontalSeparater();
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        drawSeparatedValues(row);
        drawHorizontalSeparater();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
 --- --- --- --- ---

|   |   |   |   |   |

 --- --- --- --- ---

|   |   |   |   |   |

 --- --- --- --- ---

|   |   |   |   |   |

 --- --- --- --- ---

|   |   |   |   |   |

 --- --- --- --- ---

|   |   |   |   |   |

 --- --- --- --- ---
```

Comment: The answer would be improved by adding an explanation of what your code does to address the OP's problem.